# Using Python’s fileinput with virtual file / RAM file

Tags: python, file-io

I have written some Python code to manipulate files using `fileinput` with `inplace`, which looks along the lines of this:

```python
import fileinput

def do_stuff_with_file(filename, parameters):
    for line in fileinput.input(filename, inplace=1):
        new_line = do_a_lot_of_stuff_with(line, parameters)
        print_something(line, parameters)
        print new_line,
        print_some_more(line, parameters)

do_stuff_with_file(["a.dat","b.dat"], parameters[1])
do_stuff_with_file("c.dat", parameters[2])
do_stuff_with_file("a.dat", parameters[3])
for i in range(100):
    do_stuff_with_file("d.dat", parameters[i])
```

While I call `do_stuff_with_file` usually once or twice for every file, there is one file (here, `d.dat`) for which I call it much more often, which leads to a lot of unnecessary reading and writing of that file¹.

**Are there any good ways to alter the above code** without changing the employed functions **such that this special file is read and written to only once?** I am looking for OS-independent ways, so, e.g., I cannot make a temporary copy of the file on a RAM disk or hope that the operating system is intelligent enough to avoid actually writing the file to the disk until the program is finished.

Approaches to this problem, I can think of, but which require functions, I failed to find:

- Getting `fileinput` to operate on a string instead of a file.
- “Rewinding” `fileinput` somehow.
- Do somewhat ensure that the file stays opened (and use a temporary copy).
- Find some other module that handles strings or similar using `print` like `fileinput` does.
- Create a Python-internal virtual file in some OS-independent way.

Be aware that `fileinput` realises file operations in its own peculiar way, in particular by redirecting `print` to to write to the current position of the file. Thus there is no straightforward way to use the same (or very similar) operations to modify something else, e.g., a string. This is the main reason for my problem.

Comment: Try changing this function to a class and creating a child-class of it, which should change this function slightly. That way the 'a.dat' abd 'b.dat' would be dealt in the parent class method and the 'c.dat' would be delt in the child-class method.

Comment: @f.rodrigues: How would that circumvent opening and writing `d.dat` multiple times?

Answer (score -1):

Should you prefer not to disrupt the essential structure of your code, a small *refactoring* like the following could be applied.

```
import fileinput

def do_stuff_with_file(lines, filename, parameters):
    for line in lines:
        if fileinput.filename() == filename:
            new_line = do_a_lot_of_stuff_with(line, parameters)
            print_something(line, parameters)
            print new_line,
            print_some_more(line, parameters)
        else:
            print line

filenames = ["a.dat", "b.dat", "c.dat"]
lines = fileinput.input(filenames, inplace=1)

do_stuff_with_file(lines, "a.dat", parameters)
do_stuff_with_file(lines, "b.dat", parameters)
do_stuff_with_file(lines, "a.dat", parameters)
do_stuff_with_file(lines, "c.dat", parameters)
do_stuff_with_file(lines, "c.dat", parameters)
```

Comment: After some simple tests (thus not on my code), I am pretty certain that this code will empty `b.dat` and `c.dat`, as there is not `print` statement during the iteration over `lines` during the first call of `do_stuff_with_file`. Also, all calls of `do_stuff_with_file` after the first will do nothing at all, as you can only iterate over a `fileinput.input` object once.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at your code I would move the read/write out of the do_stuff_with_file function and instead just pass data to the function. That would require you opening the file elsewhere. If you make this class as I said, you would make three methods, one for opening and closing the file, one for cleaning the memory and the other to alter-it which is called inside the first one.

```
class FileManipulation():
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
        self.data = open(self.filename,'r').read()


    def fileManage(self, parameters):
        f = open(self.filename,'w')
        output = self.do_stuff_with_file(self.data, parameters)
        f.write(output)
        f.close()

    def fileManageOpen(self):
        self.data = open(self.filename, 'r').read()

    def fileManageClose(self):
        self.data = None

    def do_stuff_with_file(self,data, parameters):
        output = None
        for line in data:
            output = do_a_lot_of_stuff_with(line, parameters)
        return output

def do_something_using(n_parameter):
    ## do something with this number
    pass

a = FileManipulation('a.dat')
b = FileManipulation('b.dat')
c = FileManipulation('c.dat')

a.fileManageOpen()
a.fileManage(do_something_using(a.data[1]))
a.fileManageClose()

b.fileManageOpen()
b.fileManage(do_something_using(b.data[2]))
b.fileManageClose()

new_parameters = []

c.fileManageOpen()    
for i in xrange(100):
    new_parameters.append(do_something_using(c.data[i]))

c.fileManage(new_parameters)
c.fileManageClose()
```

That way, only when you call fileManageOpen() you are actually reading the file, do_something() will only deal with the data already stored in the instance.

Sorry if this isn't too helpful, but your question is a bit abstract to me, I don't know why you need to open and close the file more than once if you are altering it 100 times it will remain the same.

Comment: Of course, I could process that file only once, but then I would have to write fully new code for it and could not reuse `do_stuff_with_file`.

Comment: Maybe you could, using getattr you would fetch the data of the instance(assuming you are getting the filename as string) and pass it to the do_stuff_with_file.